# Should we include #t=time anchors when linking in Documentation?

Tags: support, documentation

When I navigate to a topic in SO Documentation, the link in the URL is appended with a `#t=...` anchor. For example, if you visit:

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/209/list

The URL that you are redirected to will look something like this:

[792837b4-29ae-4088-a477-49d0b789a0f5](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/209/list#t=201608040926517252418)

I'm guessing that this is to track the time when pages are accessed, or the particular version of a page that a user *intended* you to see.

My question is, when writing/updating SODoc topics themselves, should the link be inserted with or without this `#t` anchor?

Comment: I wonder, if it ought to display the version of the page the user wants to see, why it doesn't persist the `asOf` query parameter?

Comment: Good question, if the anchor isn't needed then perhaps it should be cleaned up automatically so as to avoid confusion.

Comment: You should include it. The user will still be redirected to the latest version, but they'll have a link to the version you were seeing, which will be helpful if the page has changed dramatically or been removed. This feature lets you have the best of both worlds -- the latest version by default, with a permalinked version available.

Comment: @JeremyBanks shouldn't your comment be an answer? Also I can't see  the permalink to the original version, can you add a screenshot of its location?

Comment: @JeremyBanks Thanks, can you provide a citation that documents this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Based on Jeremy Banks' comment,
the link in the question takes you here:

[image]

Clicking on `view the older version you were linked to` leads here:

[image]

Since the default page, from a url with no timestamp, is virtually identical to the page with the timestamp, the cost of including the stamp is minimal. This behavior may be helpful in case information referenced by your question/answer changes in or is removed from the documentation.